# How to find that current url is rewritten?

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

That's no surprise that same couchapp can be build to work either with rewrites on or off.

I wonder, is there a way or a technique to find out on a client side whether rewrites are currently working, i.e. current url is rewritten?

Please share.

Comment: Huh? Wouldn't you be able to tell by curling either side of the rewrite?

Comment: @mattacular I guess, you're meaning an additional ajax request. But I'm looking for a reliable non-hackish (preferably brief) method to tell things for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Within list and show functions you can access req.requested_path that should help you with that. As of CouchDB 1.1.1, this is not working in all situations, I guess it just delivers a meaningful value if you access your CouchApp via a vhost, but I have to check that.

With CouchDB 1.2 there's a change coming that could help you with that:

https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/master/CHANGES#L103 
"The requested_path property keeps the pre-rewrite path even when no VHost configuration is matched."

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Bernhard. I'll check this too and will either accept your answer or comment.

Comment: Must confess, I fired previous comment not having  studied you answer deeply. What you told is valuable, but it doesn't answer my question, as I asked about frontend side.